# How to Handle Bit(1) type in Golang

Tags: mysql, go

when database store bit(1) type in column and we are take that type from database as bool type then i will get below error.

`couldn't convert "\x01" into type bool`

so, how to work with bit(1) type with golang and how to resolve boolean data from database.

Comment: *and we are take that type from database as bool type* BIT(1) is BINARY datatype. You may, for example, perform `SELECT bit_column + 0, ..` instead of single `SELECT bit_column, ..`, and MySQL will convert binary datatype to numeric.

Comment: but we don't need a tinyint(1) or numeric value from database.
we need if 1 then true and o means false. we need a bool value.

Comment: *we don't need a tinyint(1) or numeric value from database* But you may convert this numeric to boolean without described problem, is it? Or receive the value as binary, and search for correct binary->boolean variable datatype convertion in golang unrelatively to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

[`go-sql-driver/mysql` issue 440](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/440) does point out to the same error message.

[Gustavo Ibarra](https://github.com/gus-canya) proposes [the workaround](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/440#issuecomment-423365617):

```golang
type Transaction struct {
      IsSent           sql.NullBool   `gorm:"column:is_sent" json:"isSent,omitempty"`
}
```

with:

```
CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
  `is_sent` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
...
```

> And it worked, getting JSON response like:

```json
"isSent": {
        "Bool": true,
        "Valid": true
    },
```

---

There is also [jmoiron/sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/commit/581097f1be765de629ca6a6e0110d64e98b13267), where [Rayfen Windspear](https://github.com/RayfenWindspear) proposes a type `BitBool` Scanner/Valuer for MySQL type BIT

```
// BitBool is an implementation of a bool for the MySQL type BIT(1).
// This type allows you to avoid wasting an entire byte for MySQL's boolean type TINYINT.
type BitBool bool

// Value implements the driver.Valuer interface,
// and turns the BitBool into a bitfield (BIT(1)) for MySQL storage.
func (b BitBool) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    if b {
        return []byte{1}, nil
    } else {
        return []byte{0}, nil
    }
}

// Scan implements the sql.Scanner interface,
// and turns the bitfield incoming from MySQL into a BitBool
func (b *BitBool) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    v, ok := src.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return errors.New("bad []byte type assertion")
    }
    *b = v[0] == 1
    return nil
}
```